# Копирование, архивация и контроль версий каталогов

Tags: linux, bash

Как написать такой bash скрипт?

Народ как написать bash скрипт, которым бы я мог копировать каталог <1> в каталог <1>-<ДатаYYMMDD>, создавать архив каталога проекта в файле <1>-<ДатаYYMMDD>.<tar>. Перед созданием архива заполнять файл Manifest списком файлов всех каталогов проекта, упорядоченных по алфавиту; и заменять номер версии проекта в файле README
на номер, содержащий текущую дату с тем, чтобы в архив попадал проект из CVS.

Проект из CVS извлекается по задаваемому в параметре тегу. В архив попадает файл ChangeLog, содержащий список комментариев ко всем изменениям файла с исходным кодом. С тем чтобы в архив попадал только проект, успешно прошедший все тесты. Информация о результатах нужно записывать в test-result.html. Вообщем в результате должна работать следующим образом.

1. Проект из CVS извлекается по задаваемому в параметре тэгу.
2. Запускаются тесты, находящиеся в папке tests проекта.
3. По результатам теста формируется отчет в файле test-results.html
4. Если все тесты пройдены успешно, формируется архив проекта.

Первый абзац у меня получился так:

```
d=`date +%m.%d.%y`
cp -R LabVSI LabVSI-$d
cd F:\Lab1
touch build.xml
touch ReadMe.txt
ls -r>ReadMe.txt
cp -r -$d 
touch src
ls -r>Manifest.txt
cp -r Lab1-$d 
touch Manifest.txt
rm Manifest.txt
find .> Manifest.txt 
sed -i "1cVersion-$d" ReadMe.txt
tar -cf ../Lab1.tar F:\Lab1
```

Дальше не получается :(

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Советую вместо cp -R использовать tar, для сохранения времени и атрибутов файлов.

Зачем делать touch перед ls > ??? 

(вообще дальше, извините конечно, какая-то фигня типа cp -r -$d, touch Manifest.txt  и тут же rm Manifest.txt и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

Пример написания бэкап скрипта на bash:

[Скрипт для получения обзорной информации на тему "Что такое bash-скрипты в принципе"](http://lexpr.ru/node/368).